# Enterprise Architect - Splitting and Image/export

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have created a diagram within EA and need to export this to be included within a Word Specification. My question is, if i want the diagram to be readable i have to split it over three pages, is it possible for EA to do this or do i have to do this manually in MS Paint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're exporting the diagram.

If you're just dumping it to the clipboard or an image file, then the answer is no - what you get is a single image.

If you're generating an RTF document, the answer is yes. The relevant options are in the Diagram tab of the diagram's properties dialog, in the Page Setup and RTF Document Options groups.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have set these options and exported via an RTF